# ActiveMQ 5 redelivery policies ignored with AMQP

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, amqp, activemq-artemis

I have a Spring Boot application using Qpid JMS to speak AMQP with an ActiveMQ 5.15.14 broker. Even though the redelivery plugin is configured, the redelivery policies of the broker are ignored.  However the redelivery policy of the client (Qpid) does come into play.

When the exact same code and client configuration is connected to a ActiveMQ Artemis broker, the redelivery policy of the broker kicks in which is what I'm looking for.

Anything you are aware of that could explain this different behavior between ActiveMQ 5 and ActiveMQ Artemis? Both brokers are using pretty much OOTB configuration aside from the redelivery policies, and schedulerSupport is enabled in my ActiveMQ 5 broker as well. Here's what the redelivey configuration looks like in `activemq.xml`:

```xml
<redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true" sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
   <redeliveryPolicyMap>
      <redeliveryPolicyMap>
         <defaultEntry>
            <redeliveryPolicy initialRedeliveryDelay="5000" maximumRedeliveries="9" redeliveryDelay="60000" /> 
         </defaultEntry>
      </redeliveryPolicyMap>
   </redeliveryPolicyMap>
</redeliveryPlugin>
```

One more thing to consider : the redelivery policies of the ActiveMQ 5 broker are applied when I use Openwire (JMS) instead of AMQP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMQP protocol head in ActiveMQ 5.x is far more primitive than that of the Artemis broker implementation and is likely not reacting correct to the dispositions that are being sent back from the AMQP client.  Also the 5.x broker can react differently based on the transformer setting in the 'transportConnector' on the broker which can be one of *JMS*, *NATIVE* or *RAW*.  The *JMS* transformer will give the most ActiveMQ compatible behaviour but requires a complete transformation internally to an OpenWire message and then back to AMQP when going from AMQP sender to AMQP receiver which can hurt performance significantly.  The *NATIVE* transformation will attempt to preserve some insights into the redelivered state of the message but won't catch every case most likely.  With the *RAW* mode there will be no insight into the message delivery count at all and as such you definitely won't get any redelivery processing on the broker side.

I short, if you are looking for a fully functional AMQP broker then choose Artemis as it has had a lot of work, if you just need something that can get messages flowing then 5.x should work but don't expect the same quality of service.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you.